# Как по-русски передать название церкви Ss.Vincenzo e Anastasio, Chiesa dei Santi Vincenzo e Anastasio a Trevi?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Встретилось:

> Церковь Святого Винченцо и Анастасио в Треви;
>
> церковь Санти-Винченцо-э-Анастазио-а-Треви;
>
> церковь святых Винсента и Анастасия в Треви;
>
> церковь сщмч. Викентия и прмч. Анастасия (Рим)

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По православным канонам имена адаптируются: "(церковь) святых Викентия и Анастасия в Треви".

http://www.pravoslavie.ru/orthodoxchurches/40367.htm

Треви - наименование древнеримской административной единицы (сейчас муниципальный район). Хотя и есть рядом одноимённый фонтан, предлог ("а" обычно соответствует русскому "в") указывает на эту самую область. Chiesa (~ кьеза) - "церковь", dei - предлог родительного падежа мн. числа, е - союз "и".

Answer (score 1):

Если нет устоявшегося термина, то следует обратиться к оригиналу: la chiesa dei Santi Vincenzo e Anastasio a Trevi (английский: Saints Vincent and Anastasius at Trevi). Слово "церковь" не входит в название, а слово "Святых" - входит. Получаем: "церковь Cвятых Викентия и Анастасия в Треви"

Comment: Спасибо! Лайкну, а ЛОшечку Саше - читай его ответ! ))) Итальянец-то будет Винченцо (см. "Гусарская баллада").

Comment: Согласен с Alex_ander, правильно:  Викентия, на это не обратил внимания. Сейчас исправлю.